# Show account balance from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having following two table which stores information about Credit and Debit records.

voucherCr table contains

```
voucherType    voucherPrefix    voucherNo    crparty    cramount
SALES          S                1            1          43000
SALES          S                2            1          10000
```

voucherDr table contains

```
voucherType    voucherPrefix    voucherNo    drparty    dramount
SALES          S                1            5          43000
SALES          S                2            5          10000
```

Now here, in SALES voucher S/1, party 1 has been credit with 43000 amount agains party 5 of same amount. Same is with SALES voucher S/2, where party 1 has been credited with 10000 amount against party 5 of same amount.

Now I want to display results as follows If i query about party 1

```
PARTY    CREDIT    DEBIT    DEBITPARTY    voucherType    voucherPrefix    voucherNo
1        43000              5              SALES          S                1
1        10000              5              SALES          S                2
```

Please help

Comment: R u considering the voucherNo to match  along with the amount against the table voucherDr ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this query. Is it possible in your case that one `dramount` is divided to many rows in `voucherDr`? For example 43000->40000+3000

```
select 
vc.Party,vc.CrAmount, vd.drAmount, vd.drparty, 
vc.voucherType, vc.voucherPrefix, vc.voucherNo

from voucherCr vc
left join voucherDr vd on (vc.voucherType=vd.voucherType)
                          and (vc.voucherPrefix=vd.voucherPrefix)
                          and (vc.voucherNo=vd.voucherNo)

where vc.PARTY=1
```

Comment: @AndriyM, I wasnt rude, I need answer similar to that of Praveen

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood your question properly then this is what you are looking for

```
Select c.crParty as Party, d.dramount as credit , null as debit,
d.drParty as DEBITPARTY,c.voucherType as voucherType,
d.voucherPrefix,d.voucherNo
from VoucherCr as c inner join VoucherDr as d
on c.voucherNo=d.VoucherNo and c.voucherPrefix=d.voucherPrefix
where c.crparty=1
group by d.dramount,c.cramount,d.voucherPrefix,d.voucherNo,c.crParty,
c.voucherType,d.drParty
order by d.dramount desc
```

Try [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7e17b/11)