# Get party balance from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show account balance from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027868/show-account-balance-from-multiple-tables)

I am having two tables as follows

voucherCr

```
srno    vouchertype voucherprefix   voucherno   crparty cramount
1        PURCHASE       P              1            2   55000
2        PAYMENT        R              1            1   55000
```

voucherDr

```
srno    vouchertype voucherprefix   voucherno   drparty dramount
1        PURCHASE       P              1            4   54000
2        PAYMENT        R              1            2   55000
3        PURCHASE       P              1            4       1000
```

Here, in PURCHASE voucher P/1, I am purchasing goods from party 2 worth of 55000
and in PAYMENT voucher R/1, I am paying 55000 rupees to party 2.

Now If i query about party 2, I want to display information in following format

```
VTYPE      VPRE      VNO      AGAINSTPARTY      CREDIT      DEBIT
PURCHASE   P         1        4                 55000       NULL
PAYMENT    R         1        1                 NULL        55000
```

So the closing balance for party 2 will be zero, as I have paid them 55000 against the purchase of 55000

Can you help me?

**Update**
I tried with following but no result

```
select * from voucherCr vc
full outer join voucherDr vd
on vc.voucherno=vd.voucherno
and vc.voucherprefix=vd.voucherprefix
and vc.vouchertype=vd.vouchertype
where vc.crparty=2 or vd.drparty=2
```

**Update 2**

I am getting wrong results if there are multiple entries in either of the table for the same voucherno and voucherprefix.

Comment: @marc_s, I am using MSSQL Server 2008

Comment: Can you please explain better the meaning of fields and how do they relate each other, i.e. primary and foreign keys

Comment: @remigio, In both the tables, vouchertype,voucherprefix,voucherno fields are common, which stores voucher information. CRPARTY contains party no which is credited. DRPARTY contains party no which is debited. Same is with DRAMOUNT and CRAMOUNT.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this:

```
select C.vouchertype,C.voucherprefix,C.voucherno,D.drparty,C.cramount AS CREDIT,NULL as DEBIT
from voucherCr C
inner join voucherDr D on C.vouchertype=D.vouchertype and C.voucherprefix=D.voucherprefix    and C.voucherno=D.voucherno
and C.crparty=2
union
select D.vouchertype,D.voucherprefix,D.voucherno,C.crparty,NULL as CREDIT,D.dramount AS   DEBIT
from voucherCr C
inner join voucherDr D on C.vouchertype=D.vouchertype and C.voucherprefix=D.voucherprefix and C.voucherno=D.voucherno
and D.Drparty=2
```

Comment: I have updated my problem with Update 2, Please go through and let me know If you can help

Comment: Can you please explain better, what do you mean with wrong results?

Comment: I have updated my voucherDr table with another entry, please see the result with your query

Comment: The result is the same with the old query, what should it be?

Answer (score 0):

```
`SELECT *   
 FROM voucherCr VC  
   FULL OUTER JOIN voucherDr VD ON VC.crparty = VD.drparty  
 WHERE  
   (VC.crparty IS NULL OR VD.drparty IS NULL)`
```

Sample: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/74419/45